# Calculate up to 15 decimal places with precision

Tags: c#, precision

How do I calculate up to 15 decimal places with precision? In this example I have 3 doubles in `List<double>`

```
4.080000000000001
22.830000000000002
307.5
```

Here is the code:

```
List<double> values = new List<double> { 4.080000000000001, 22.830000000000002, 307.5 };

var result = values.Sum();
```

result is equal to `334.41`

How do I calculate this to precision which should be?

```
334.410000000000003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `System.Decimal` type instead of `System.Double`

```
List<decimal> decimals = new List<decimal>() 
{ 4.080000000000001m, 22.830000000000002m, 307.5m };
decimal result = decimals.Sum();
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Result: `334.410000000000003`

Note that you need to use the 'm' affix on your literals to denote that it is a decimal literal rather than a double.